# Why am i getting segmentation ? malloc() corrupted topsize

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{

    for(int i=0; envp[i]!=NULL; i++)
        printf("%d.%s\n", i , envp[i]);
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    int maxim = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        int k=0;
        for(int j=0;envp[i][j]!=NULL; j++)
            k++;
        if(k>maxim)
            maxim=k;
    }
    char *string = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char)+1)*maxim);
    for(int i=0; envp[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        strcpy(string, envp[i]);
        for(int j=0;string[j]!=NULL;j++)
            if(string[j] == '=')
            {
                string[j]='\0';
                break;
            }
        if(i%2 == 0)
            setenv(string, "London", 1);
    }
    for(int i=0; envp[i]!=NULL; i++)
        printf("%d.%s\n", i , envp[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to change the value of the enviorment var that is on an even pozition to "LONDON"

Comment: What is the point of: `for(int i=0; i<1; i++)`? A 'loop' that executes once, by design, is not worthy of being called a loop.

Comment: `string[j]!=NULL` You are dealing with `char`. `NULL` is normally used for pointers.

Comment: `malloc((sizeof(char)+1)*maxim);` What is this `+1` supposed to mean? Did you mean `malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxim+1));`?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<1; i++)` is the problem here. You want to loop over all environnment variables to get the length of the longest one, but you only "loop" over the first one. OTOH you do it correctly in the second for loop.

Comment: Aside: This may just be an MRE, but my understanding is that the process will only modify its own copy of the environment variable (if that.) This cannot be a "standalone" executable with any persistent effect. (And God help its children...)

Comment: @Fe203 You're right! Each process has a separate copy of the environment. A child process cannot affect its parent in any way: can't alter the environment, can't change the working directory, or anything. It can return it's exit status, though (If the parents waits for it to return ;).

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd for loop you determine the length of the key=value string of the first environment variable.  On my system that of the string "SHELL=/bin/bash" so`maxism=15`.

Then you allocate your string:

```
    char *string = malloc(2*maxim);
```

and then iterate through all environment variables and copy those to `string`.  As my largest envp[i] is LS_COLORS which is 1519 bytes this will trigger a buffer overflow.

The minimal fix is to:

1. Iterate through all of envp to find `maxim`.
2. Size string`differently to avoid the potential issue of`2 * maxium < strlen(key[i]) + sizeof('=') + strlen("London")`.  It may not happen in practice but an attacker may manipulate the environment to make it so.
3. Eliminate the `!= NULL` mainly to address the warning when the lhs is of type char and rhs should have been `!= '\0'`.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    for(int i=0; envp[i]; i++)
        printf("%d.%s\n", i , envp[i]);
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    int maxim = -1;
    for(int i=0; envp[i]; i++) {
        int k=0;
        for(int j=0;envp[i][j]; j++)
            k++;
        if(k>maxim)
            maxim=k;
    }
    char *string = malloc(maxim + sizeof("London"));
    for(int i=0; envp[i]; i++) {
        strcpy(string, envp[i]);
        for(int j=0;string[j]; j++)
            if(string[j] == '=') {
                string[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        if(i%2 == 0)
            setenv(string, "London", 1);
    }
    for(int i=0; envp[i]; i++)
        printf("%d.%s\n", i , envp[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

You could simplify your code by:

1. Write function to print the environment as you do it twice.
2. Use `strlen()` 2nd for-loop instead of calculating it manually.
3. In the 4th loop iterate over every 2nd element as it's the only ones being modified.  Use `strchr(envp[p], '=')` to find the position of `=` then use `strncpy()` to only copy the key instead of the whole thing that you then have to post-process:

```
    for(int i=0; envp[i]; i+=2) {
        char *equal = strchr(envp[i], '=');
        if(!equal) continue; // key without = possible?
        strncpy(string, envp[i], equal - envp[i]);
        string[equal - envp[i]] = '\0';
        setenv(string, "London", 1);
    }
```